# devops pipeline yaml ignore failed test for DotNetCoreCLI@2 task

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a devops yaml pipeline that runs DotNetCoreCLI@2 tasks to restore, build and test.

In the event, one or more tests fail I would like the pipeline to continue and publish the output ready for the devops release.

Initially, for a failed test the whole pipeline execution would report "Build Failed". After adding the following at the top of the build pipeline yaml:

```
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    continueOnError: true
```

I now get "Build Partially Succeeded".

However, when I check the pipeline execution summary page, I see there are 0 artifacts:

[image]

How can I make the pipeline publish even if the tests fail?

For completeness, the full yaml is below

```
    stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    continueOnError: true

    pool:
      name: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
      demands:
      - msbuild
      - visualstudio

    variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      projects: '**/Interfaces.Avaloq.Presentation.AzureFunctions.csproj'
      unitTestProjects: '**/*Testing.Unit*/*.csproj'
      integrationTestProjects: '**/*Testing.Integration*/*.csproj'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

    steps:
    - script: |
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Restore Functions
      inputs:
        command: restore
        projects: '$(projects)'
        feedsToUse: config
        nugetConfigPath: nuget.config
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build Functions
      inputs:
        command: build
        projects: '$(projects)'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Restore Unit Tests
      inputs:
        command: restore
        projects: '$(unitTestProjects)'
        feedsToUse: config
        nugetConfigPath: nuget.config
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build Unit Tests
      inputs:
        command: build
        projects: '$(unitTestProjects)'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Run Unit Tests
      inputs:
        command: 'test'
        projects: '$(unitTestProjects)'
        arguments: --filter Category!=ExcludeFromBVT
        testRunTitle: 'Unit Tests'
        feedsToUse: config
        nugetConfigPath: nuget.config
    
    - task: AzurePowerShell@4
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'Design Subscription (xxx)'
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: |
          Set-Location $env:AGENT_WORKFOLDER
          Get-ChildItem -Recurse
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        projects: '$(projects)'
        publishWebProjects: false
        zipAfterPublish: true

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: ArmTemplate'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: Interfaces.Avaloq.Deployment
        ArtifactName: RGDeploy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your test are failing please add `continueOnError: true` on test step level. Adding it on job level causes that next (dependent) job will run. Please compare this:

- continueOnError on job level:
  [image]
- continueOnError on step level:
  [image]